# Google drive OR Google cloud storage for a business web app

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage

I'm a voice-over artist. I am creating a web app in which the client can make orders & upload video/sound/image/text files, I download these files to edit them then i upload the edited files & allow the client to download them.

Which is better for this purpose?

**Taking in consideration**

- I want to allow the client to preview the edited file (video) in the
  browser
- Security
- File privacy [I mean no one can reach the file except the client who made the order]
- Performance
- Price

Answer (score 0):

There is no definitive answer to your question.

It confuses many customers that two, such seemingly functionally similar services, are available.

That said -- *generally* -- for applications where a service (your web app) is the intermediary, Google Cloud Storage (GCS) is the more appropriate solution.

GCS is a lower-level service than Drive and so you'll have a little more work to do to integrate it but it provides richer functionality too particularly with regards authorization and being able to provide more specificity about who can do what. Lastly, GCS enables so-called "[Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)" that would e.g. permit you to provide your customers with a secure and time-bound URL where they may upload content.

One possibly determining feature is that a Google Drive account is oriented around an individual (generally human) user (e.g. you) and your Google Drive does not permit other users to upload files; only you can create files in your Drive account although you can then share these with others.

I hope this helps you decide which service is best-suited to your needs. GCS is a very widely used service and is well-documented. You should be able to find plenty of guidance to help you develop a solution using it.